# Pie language: Manual vs Real life

Tags: racket, pie-lang

For the new scheme-like, dependently-typed language 'Pie', I purchased the language's companion book: The Little Typer (http://thelittletyper.com/)

I'm trying to follow along with the code using DrRacket, but I'm getting on errors when I type the code in the book.

```
(cons 'ratatouille 'baguette)
```

I get this error:
"Can't determine a type"

Since both of the symbols are Atoms, shouldn't that call to cons work?

Also, the '+' function is undefined, even for numbers. Does Pie have prelude that can be imported to provide such basic things.

Comment: To my recollection, Pie doesn't have + function built in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
#lang pie
(the (Pair Atom Atom)
  (cons 'foo 'foo))
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this the right answer, even if it makes the error go away, honestly. Since I'm unsure, I'll leave this response unaccepted, for now.

Comment: In my opinion this is the correct answer. This is discussed further in [The Little Typer](http://thelittletyper.com/) in the chapter titled "A Forkful of Pie", around frame 11.